# How to mock field type Resource of Spring with JUNIT5 and Mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito, junit5

I have a class that reads JSON File from my directory, but I Could't mock the Resource field:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class MyClass{

   
  @Value("classpath:file.json")
  private Resource resourceFile;

  public MyDTO getInfoFromJSONFile() {
    try {
        
     //Read file
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new MyException("General Error");
    }
  }
```

This my test:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:file.json" })
class MyClassTest{

    private MyClass subject;

    @Mock
    private Resource resourceFile;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.subject = new MyClass();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     }

    @Test
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"myParam"})
    void testReadInfoFromJsonFileSuccessfully(String param){
        MyDTO myDTO= subject.getInfoFromJSONFile(providerConfigId);
        Assertions.assertEquals(myDTO.getMyField(), "VALUE");
    }
}
```

The field resourceFile never is initialized with a mock value, How can I mock this type of field ?

Answer (score 4):

Mockito `@Mock` does not perform Spring Dependency Injection mechanism. It just creates a mock and assigns it to the `resourceFile` field inside your test suite.

There are two options:

1. Replace field injection with constructor injection and put the value manually.

```java
public class MyClass{
  private Resource resourceFile;

  public MyClass(@Value("classpath:file.json") Resource resourceFile) {
    this.resourceFile = resourceFile;
  }
}

class MyClassTest{

    private MyClass subject;

    @Mock
    private Resource resourceFile;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.subject = new MyClass(resourceFile);
     }
}
```

2. Apply `@SpringBootTest` to run the Spring Context and proceed the bean lifecycle.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class MyClassTest{
    @Autowired
    private MyClass subject;
    ...
}
```

Though in this case, you won't be able to mock `Resource`. Instead, you should put the file with required content to `test/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

solution  3:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyClassTest{

@InjectMocks
private MyClass subject;

@Mock
private Resource resourceFile;
@Test
public void tesetMethod(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("file.json");
    Mockito.when(resource.getInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);

 
}
```

}